# How to show TabBar label only on active Tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to hide the TabBar Label when the tab is not active.
With `showLabel` from tabBarOptions I can only disable them completely.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Material Design TabBar]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey Drew thanks for the idea, couldn't figure it out on my own, but I think you have a lot of extra code unnecessary for the functionality asked in the question. Here is my take on this, and this works just as well.

```
export const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    News: {
      screen: NewsNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }: any) =>
          focused ? <NewsIconActive /> : <NewsIcon />
      }
    },
    Rewards: {
      screen: RewardsNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }: any) =>
          focused ? <RewardsIconActive /> : <RewardsIcon />
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }: any) =>
          focused ? <HomeIconActive /> : <HomeIcon />
      }
    },
    Leaderboard: {
      screen: LeaderboardNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }: any) =>
          focused ? <LeaderboardIconActive /> : <LeaderboardIcon />
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }: any) =>
          focused ? <ProfileIconActive /> : <ProfileIcon />
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Profile'
    },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        switch (routeName) {
          case 'News':
            return focused ? (
              <Text>{routeName}</Text>
            ) : null;
            break;
          case 'Rewards':
            return focused ? (
              <Text>{routeName}</Text>
            ) : null;
            break;
          case 'Home':
            return focused ? (
              <Text>{routeName}</Text>
            ) : null;
            break;
          case 'Leaderboard':
            return focused ? (
              <Text >{routeName}</Text>
            ) : null;
            break;
          case 'Profile':
            return focused ? (
              <Text>{routeName}</Text>
            ) : null;
            break;
          default:
            return null;
            break;
        }
      }
    })
  }
);
```

Answer (score 7):

This fairly simple solution worked for me in version 5 of React Navigation:

```
<Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => {
        return { tabBarLabel: navigation.isFocused() ? route.name : '' };
    }}
>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had trouble with this too but found a solution that may help you. Check out how I configure `tabBarIcon` and `tabBarLabel` below:

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: HomeStack,
    MyProsthetic: MyProstheticStack,
    Appointments: AppointmentsStack,
    MyNotes: MyNotesStack,
    Contact: ContactStack,
 },
 {
 navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    let icon;
    switch(routeName) {
      case 'Home':
        tabBarLabel = true
        return icon = <Icon name='home' size={30} color={focused ? Colors.darkBlue : Colors.lightGrey} />
      case 'MyProsthetic':
        return icon = <Icon name='user' size={28} color={focused ? Colors.darkBlue : Colors.lightGrey} />
      case 'Appointments':
        return icon = <IonIcon name='md-calendar' size={32} color={focused ? Colors.darkBlue : Colors.lightGrey} style={{position: 'relative', top: 3}}/>
      case 'MyNotes':
        return icon = <Icon name='file' size={23} color={focused ? Colors.darkBlue : Colors.lightGrey} />
      case 'Contact':
        return icon = <Icon name='phone' size={30} color={focused ? Colors.darkBlue : Colors.lightGrey} />

    }
    return icon
  },
  tabBarLabel: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    let label;
    switch(routeName) {
      case 'Home':
        return label = focused ? <Text style={styles.activeTabText}>Home</Text> : null
      case 'MyProsthetic':
        return label = focused ? <Text style={styles.activeTabText}>My Prosthetic</Text> : null
      case 'Appointments':
        return label = focused ? <Text style={styles.activeTabText}>Appointments</Text> : null
      case 'MyNotes':
        return label = focused ? <Text style={styles.activeTabText}>Notes</Text> : null
      case 'Contact':
        return label = focused ? <Text style={styles.activeTabText}>Contact</Text> : null
    }
    return label
  },
}),
lazy: false,
tabBarOptions: {
  style: {
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: Colors.lightGrey
  },
}
}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With version 5.x you can just use "shifting" [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/#shifting][1] which default is true only for number of tabs > 3

```
<Tab.Navigator
      shifting
    >
```

EDIT: As noted this is valid only for material bottom tab bar

Comment: it's only work with material tab not with react native bottom tab

Answer (score 1):

i did this with V6 :

```
screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
         tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
                        let label;
                        return label = focused ? <Text style={{fontSize: 10, color: "gray"}}>{route.name}</Text> : null
                      }})
```

Answer (score 0):

`tabBarLabel` did the trick!

```js
<NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => {
            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              return (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size={25} color={color} />);
            } else if (route.name === 'Location') {
              return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMapMarker} size={25} color={color} />;
            } else if (route.name === 'Alerts') {
              return (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBell} size={25} color={color} />);
            } else if (route.name === 'Store') {
              return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStore} size={25} color={color} />;
            } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
              return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} size={25} color={color} />;
            }
          },
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => {
            let label;
            switch (route.name) {
              case 'Home':
                return label = focused ? <Text style={{ color }}>Home</Text> : null
              case 'Location':
                return label = focused ? <Text style={{ color }}>Location</Text> : null
              case 'Alerts':
                return label = focused ? <Text style={{ color }}>Alerts</Text> : null
              case 'Store':
                return label = focused ? <Text style={{ color }}>Store</Text> : null
              case 'Profile':
                return label = focused ? <Text style={{ color }}>Profile</Text> : null
            }
            return label
          }
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: 'blue', inactiveTintColor: 'gray' }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Location" component={LocationStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Alerts" component={AlertsStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Store" component={StoreStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer >
```